# Image annotation in angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, annotations

> This is the angualrapp what i written in angular4, I just got image annotation in angular1.x the link below.
>   I converted it into angular4(typescript)
>   [This is image annotation code which is in angular1.x](https://github.com/igorlino/angular-annotorious)

```js
> This was actually in controller.ts in given link but i changed it into (angular component class) angualar4.

app.component.ts:
-------------------------------

import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


//Services 
// import { ColorboxService } from './colorbox.service';
import { AnnotoriousService } from './annotorious.service';
import { AnnotoriousLocalstorageService } from './annotorious-localstorage.service';
//Ends Services

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  approot: any;
  zoomModel1: any;
  zoomModel2: any;
  zoomModelGallery01  : any;
  zoomModelGallery04: any;
  zoomModelGallery05: any;
  annotateColorbox01: any;
    //Constructor
  constructor( private annotorious: AnnotoriousService){
    //default
    // this.setApproot('');
  }
  ngOnInit(){
      let appRoot: string = '';
      this.setApproot(appRoot);
  }
 setApproot(appRoot){
    //only change when needed.
        // var appRoot: any;
    if (this.approot && appRoot === this.approot) {
        return;
    }
    this.approot = appRoot;
    Object.assign(this.annotateColorbox01, {
        href: appRoot + 'images/large/image4.jpg',
        className: 'colorbox-to-annotate',
        onComplete() {
            let $ : any;
            let photo = $("#cboxLoadedContent .cboxPhoto")[0];
            if (photo.src) {
                // console.log('annotateColorbox01 ' + photo.src);
                this.Annotorious.makeAnnotatable(photo);
                let annotations = this.Annotorious.getAnnotations(photo.src);
                // console.log(annotations);
                if (this.annotations && this.annotations.length > 0) {
                  this.Annotorious.showAnnotations(photo.src);
                }

            }
        },
        onCleanup() {
            //alert('onCleanupa ');
            this.annotatableImage();
        }
    });
}; 

}

> This is annotorious service i changed it fom angular1.x to 4

Annotorious.service.ts:
--------------------------

import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


//Services 
// import { ColorboxService } from './colorbox.service';
import { AnnotoriousService } from './annotorious.service';
import { AnnotoriousLocalstorageService } from './annotorious-localstorage.service';
//Ends Services

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  approot: any;
  zoomModel1: any;
  zoomModel2: any;
  zoomModelGallery01  : any;
  zoomModelGallery04: any;
  zoomModelGallery05: any;
  annotateColorbox01: any;
    //Constructor
  constructor( private annotorious: AnnotoriousService){
    //default
    // this.setApproot('');
  }
  ngOnInit(){
      let appRoot: string = '';
      this.setApproot(appRoot);
  }
 setApproot(appRoot){
    //only change when needed.
        // var appRoot: any;
    if (this.approot && appRoot === this.approot) {
        return;
    }
    this.approot = appRoot;
    Object.assign(this.annotateColorbox01, {
        href: appRoot + 'images/large/image4.jpg',
        className: 'colorbox-to-annotate',
        onComplete() {
            let $ : any;
            let photo = $("#cboxLoadedContent .cboxPhoto")[0];
            if (photo.src) {
                // console.log('annotateColorbox01 ' + photo.src);
                this.Annotorious.makeAnnotatable(photo);
                let annotations = this.Annotorious.getAnnotations(photo.src);
                // console.log(annotations);
                if (this.annotations && this.annotations.length > 0) {
                  this.Annotorious.showAnnotations(photo.src);
                }

            }
        },
        onCleanup() {
            //alert('onCleanupa ');
            this.annotatableImage();
        }
    });
}; 

}

> This is angular annotorious service which is in angular 4

annotorious.localstorage.ts:
-----------------------------------

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AnnotoriousService } from './annotorious.service';

@Injectable()
export class AnnotoriousLocalstorageService {

    annotorious : any;
    constructor(private annotoriousSer: AnnotoriousService) { 
        this.annotorious.plugin.Parse.prototype.initPlugin = this.initPlugin;
        this.annotorious.plugin.Parse.prototype.onInitAnnotator = this.onInitAnnotator;

        //private methods
        this.annotorious.plugin.Parse.prototype._newLoadIndicator = this._newLoadIndicator;
        this.annotorious.plugin.Parse.prototype._loadAnnotations = this._loadAnnotations;
        this.annotorious.plugin.Parse.prototype._create = this._create;
        this.annotorious.plugin.Parse.prototype._update = this._update;
        this.annotorious.plugin.Parse.prototype._delete = this._delete;

        this.annotoriousSer.getAnnotorious().addPlugin('Parse', {debug: true});
  }

   DEBUG = false;
   found: any;
   uuid4: any;**strong text**
        getAnnotations() {
            /* jshint validthis: true */
            var localStorageService : any;
            var self = this;
            var annotationsCache = localStorageService.get('annotationsCache');
            //if not existing, use an array
            if (!annotationsCache) {
                annotationsCache = [];
                localStorageService.set('annotationsCache', annotationsCache);
            }
            if (this.DEBUG) {
                console.log('annotorious-storage:getAnnotations:' + annotationsCache.length);
            }
            return annotationsCache;
        }

        saveAnnotations(annotationsCache) {
            /* jshint validthis: true */
            var self = this;
            var localStorageService: any;
            //if not existing, use an array
            if (annotationsCache) {
                var result = localStorageService.set('annotationsCache', annotationsCache);
            }
            if (this.DEBUG) {
                console.log('annotorious-storage:setAnnotations:' + annotationsCache.length);
            }
            return annotationsCache;
        }

        initPlugin(anno) {
            /* jshint validthis: true */
            var self = this;
            var _create : any;
            var _update : any;
            var _delete : any;
            if (this.DEBUG) {
                console.log('annotorious-storage:initPlugin');
            }

            anno.addHandler('onAnnotationCreated',  (annotation) => {
                _create(annotation);
            });

            anno.addHandler('onAnnotationUpdated',  (annotation) => {
                _update(annotation);
            });

            anno.addHandler('onAnnotationRemoved', (annotation) => {
                _delete(annotation);
            });
        }

        onInitAnnotator(annotator) {
            /* jshint validthis: true */
            var self = this;
            var _loadAnnotations : any;
            var _loadIndicators : any;
            if (self.DEBUG) {
                console.log('annotorious-storage:onInitAnnotator');
            }
            _loadAnnotations(this.annotoriousSer.getAnnotorious());

            var spinner = self._newLoadIndicator();
            annotator.element.appendChild(spinner);
            _loadIndicators.push(spinner);
        }

        _newLoadIndicator() {
            var outerDIV = document.createElement('div');
            outerDIV.className = 'annotorious-parse-plugin-load-outer';

            var innerDIV = document.createElement('div');
            innerDIV.className = 'annotorious-parse-plugin-load-inner';

            outerDIV.appendChild(innerDIV);
            return outerDIV;
        }

        _loadAnnotations(anno) {
            /* jshint validthis: true */
            var self = this;
             var lodash : any;
            var annotations = self.getAnnotations();
            lodash.forEach(annotations,  (annotation) => {
                if (annotation.shapes && annotation.shapes.length > 0 && annotation.shapes[0].geometry) {
                    anno.addAnnotation(annotation);
                }
            });
        }

        _create(annotationData) {
            /* jshint validthis: true */
            var self = this;
            var annotations = self.getAnnotations();
            annotationData.objectId = this.uuid4.generate();
            annotations.push(annotationData);
            self.saveAnnotations(annotations);
        }

        _update(annotationData) {
            /* jshint validthis: true */
            var self = this;
            var _create : any;
            var annotations = self.getAnnotations();
            var found = true;
            for (var j = 0; j < annotations.length; j++) {
                if (annotationData.objectId === annotations[j].objectId) {
                    annotations[j] = annotationData;
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                _create(annotationData);
            }
            this.saveAnnotations(annotations);
        }

        _delete(annotationData) {
            /* jshint validthis: true */
            var self = this;
            var annotations = this.getAnnotations();
            var found = null;
            for (var j = 0; j < annotations.length; j++) {
                if (annotationData.objectId === annotations[j].objectId) {
                    annotations[j] = annotationData;
                    found = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found != null) {
                annotations.splice(j, 1);
                this.saveAnnotations(annotations);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Igor Lino">
    <title>Angular Annotorious Demo</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
        }

        .starter-template {
            padding: 40px 15px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/igorlino/elevatezoom-plus/master/css/jquery.ez-plus.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src='https://rawgit.com/igorlino/elevatezoom-plus/master/src/jquery.ez-plus.js'></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" /> -->
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/igorlino/annotorious-bower/master/css/annotorious.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/igorlino/angular-colorbox/master/themes/dark/colorbox-darktheme.css" media="screen" />

    <script src='https://rawgit.com/igorlino/annotorious-bower/master/annotorious.min.js'></script>

    <script src='https://rawgit.com/igorlino/angular-colorbox/master/js/angular-colorbox.js'></script>

    <script src='https://rawgit.com/igorlino/angular-elevatezoom-plus/master/js/angular-ezplus.js'></script>

    <!--
    <script src='https://rawgit.com/igorlino/angular-annotorious/master/js/angular-annotorious.js'></script>
    -->
    <!-- <script src='../js/angular-annotorious.js'></script> -->

    <!--
    <script src='https://rawgit.com/igorlino/angular-annotorious/master/demo/controller.js'></script>
    <script src='https://rawgit.com/igorlino/angular-annotorious/master/demo/app.js'></script>
    -->
    <script src='controller.js'></script>
    <script src='app.js'></script>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.4.33/jquery.colorbox.js'></script>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js'></script>

    <!-- latest includes-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://annotorious.github.com/latest/annotorious.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://annotorious.github.com/latest/annotorious.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-annotorious.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ends latest includes-->


</head>

<body ng-init="setApproot('')">

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Angular Annotorious</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">
      
        <img
            width="500px"
            src="{{approot}}../assets/images/large/image5.jpg"
            annotorious-annotate
            />

    </div>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

</body>
</html>
```

[This is error when I try to run my code on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWJS6.png)
[here is the code for my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBupP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use Javascript file which is already using in angular/ javascript for annotations

```js
app.componet.ts
-----------------


import 'annototion.js';

export class appComponet{

constructor(){

  // try your code here..
}

}
```

Comment: But I want completely in angular4, without using Javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

Simple use global window object to access the anno object in ***.ts*** file:

`anno = window['anno'];`